# How to prove that the following simplification rule on Davis–Putnam function is satisfiability-equivalent?

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

Denote $F\stackrel{\text{SAT}}{\equiv}H$ if $F \in SAT {\iff} H \in SAT$.

A transformation of formulas $S(·)$ is called satisfiability-equivalent if $\forall{F}\space F\stackrel{\text{SAT}}{\equiv}S(F)$.

How to prove that the following simplification rule is satisfiability-equivalent and
show how to re-construct a satisfying assignment for the original formula $F$ from a satisfying assignment for
the simplified formula:
**${DP}_x(F)$ (the rule transforms F into ${DP}_x(F)$.**

***Note:-*** ${DP}_x(F)$  is the Davis–Putnam formula. The Davis–Putnam procedure eliminates variables one by one using the following function:

**Function ${DP}_x(F)$**
(// simplifies $F$
by getting rid of $x$
)

1. Add all resolvents by $x$
   to $F$.
2. Remove all clauses containing $x$ or $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Maybe useful [DPPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm). Are you saying: 1) assign a truth value to $x$, e.g. $\top$; 2) replace all clauses $C_i$ where $x$ occurs with $C_i[\top / x]$; 3) remove every clauses $C_j$ where the tautological $x \lor \lnot x$ occur.?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My question is that how to prove simplification rule that is satisfiability-equivalent? Here the rule is "the rule transforms F into ${DP}_x(F).$ Here ${DP}_x(F)$ is the resulting formula not the function. I have defined function explicitly in the question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Your above explanation may be sufficient for the proof , you can put by all these above comments can create  an answer. But one thing use equivalent definition defined in the question $F\stackrel{\text{SAT}}{\equiv}H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davis%E2%80%93Putnam_algorithm) can be described as follows.

Select a literal $l_i$ (a variable or the complement of a variable) and apply the algorithm recursively to search for a satisfying assignment for
the formula $F[l_i \leftarrow \bot]$, i.e. the formula obtaind assigning False to literal $l_i$.

If the search succeeds, then we have a satisfying assignment for $F$. Otherwise, repeat the search with the formula $F[l_i \leftarrow \top]$.

If neither of these searches finds a satisfying assignment, then $F$ is *unsatisfiable*.

The procedure is based on the [resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) saying that if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are clauses containing two complemantry literal $x$ and $\lnot x$ i.e. $C_1$ is $D_1 \lor x$ and $C_2$ is $D_2 \lor \lnot x$, then any assignment that satisfies both clauses $C_1$ and $C_2$ also satisfies $D_1 \lor D_2$. The clause $D_1 \lor D_2$ is said to be a *resolvent* of the original clauses (called *parent* clauses) on the variable $x$.

If we agree on this, we have to show that to resolve a pair of clauses with complementary literals $x$ and $\lnot x$ (step 1) preserves satisfiability: see below.

Regarding step 2, a "tautological" clause $x \lor ¬x$ is always satisfiable (it is equivalent to $\top$); thus every clause containing a "tautological" part has form $\alpha \lor \top$ and can be removed because it is satisfiable.

---

Now for the proof of the main result:

(i) Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be satisfiable under an interpretation I. Since $x$ and $\lnot x$ are complementary, either $I(x) = \top$ or $I(\lnot x) = \top$. Suppose that $I(x) = \top$; then $I(\lnot x) = \bot$ and $C_2 = D_2 \lor \lnot x$ can be satisfied only if $I(D_2) = \top$.

But the resolvent $C$ is $D_1 \lor D_2$, and thus $I$ is also a model of it. A symmetric argument holds if $I(\lnot x) = \top$.

(ii) Conversely, let $I$ be an interpretation which satisfies $C$; then $I(l) = \top$ for at least one literal $l$ occurring in $C$.

By the resolution rule, either $l$ occurs in $C_1$ or $l$ occurs in $C_2$ (or both). In the first case we have $I(C_1) = \top$. Since neither $x$ nor $\lnot x$ occur in the resolvent $C$, the (partial) interpretation $I$ is not defined on them, and we can extend it to an "larger" one $I'$ defining $I'(\lnot x) = \top$.

Since $C_2$ is $D_2 \lor \lnot x$, we have $I'(C_2) = \top$ and $I'(C_1) = I(C_1) = \top$; so $I'$ is a model for both $C_1$ and $C_2$. A symmetric argument holds if $l$ occurs in $C_2$.

Conclusion: let $F$ the formula and let $H$ the "transformed" one. Starting from $I$ such that $I(H)=\top$, and thus $I$ satisfies the resolvent $C$, we define $I'$ that is equal to $I$ plus the condition that $I'(\lnot x)= \top$ or not according to the way that $I$ satisfies the resolvent clause.

Comment: I have one [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/165163/how-to-write-an-algorithm-for-xor-equations-problem-using-the-dpll-approach), actually torturing me from long time. Actually you are expert on this subject, you might help me.

Comment: @AdamHymen - I know the logic but I'm not an expert in implementation... Maybe useful [here](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~beame/papers/resj.pdf)

Comment: In DP_x(F), we add all the resolvents by x and remove all the clauses that contain the variable x (either positively or negatively).
Therefore, you have to reconstruct the value of x so that all the removed clauses are satisfied. So how to do that? Would you edit the answer by clearing this concept.

Comment: @AdamHymen - not clear. The gist is that we have two clauses $\lnot P \lor Q$ and $P \lor R$ and we *resolve* them using the pair of compelmentary literals generating the resolvent $Q \lor R$. The resolution rule preserves *satisfiability* because if the two clauses were sat, then one of $Q$ and $R$ must be True, and thus also $Q \lor R$ is. And viceversa.

Comment: We want replace F by H:= DP_x(F), and we need to reconstruct a satisfying assignment for F from a satisfying assignment for H.

Comment: @AdamHymen - F is the original and H is the "transformed" one. In F we have the pair $C_1$ and $C_2$ as above and we have the resolvent $C=D_1 \lor D_2$ that is satisfied by $I$. This means that there is $l \in C$ such that $I(l)=\top$. Either $l \in C_1$ or $l \in C_2$ because all literals in $C$ derive from those of the original pair of clauses. Then [re-read last step above] if $l \in C_1$ from $I(l)=\top$ we have $I(C_1)=⊤$. Since neither ..., we can extend $I$ to $I′$ defining $I′(¬x)=⊤$ and thus $I'(C_2)=I'(D_2 \lor ¬x)=⊤$.

Comment: The gist is that we have two clauses $¬P∨Q$ and $P∨R$ and we resolve them using the pair of compelmentary literals generating the resolvent $Q∨R.$  This is right. But my question is that if $¬P∨Q'$ and $P∨R'$, then the resolvent is  $Q'∨R'$. Then what happens in this case how $Q'∨R'$ becomes true, if both Q and R are true?

Comment: IF those are the clauses to be resolved  the resolvent will be $Q' \lor R'$ and all the machinery above will be applied to it.

Comment: What are the machinery applied to it? Explain little bit.

Comment: I have written it twice:-) what is Q'? Another formula? A litetal?

Comment: It's clause. I mean that if ¬x∨Q′ and x∨R′, then the resolvent is Q′∨R′. Then what happens in this case how Q′∨R′ becomes true, if both Q and R are true. So Q, R is literal or clause, as D1, D2 in your answer but D1∨D2 is clause.

Comment: And this is my concern... I have used $D_1 \lor x$ and $D_2 \lor \lnot x$ and you are using $x \lor R'$ and $\lnot x \lor Q'$: what is the difference?

Comment: You said one of at least D1 and D2 is true, but question is that when both are false, how to acquire this case?